# Mean of values before and after a specific element

Tags: average, mean

I have an array of 1 x 400, where all element values are above 1500. However, I have some elements that have values<50 which are wrong measures and  I would like to have the mean of the elements before and after the wrong measured data points and replace it in the main array.
For instance, element number 17 is below 50 so I want to take the mean of elements 16 and 18 and replace element 17 with the new mean.
Can someone help me, please? many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share some code you already have?

What language are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No language is specified in the question, but for Python you could work with [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```py
# array with 400 values, some of which are incorrect
arr = [...]

arr = [arr[i] if arr[i] >= 50 else (arr[i-1]+arr[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(arr))]
```

That is, if arr[i] is less than 50, it'll be replaced by the average value of the element before and after it. There are two issues with this approach.

1. If i is the first or last element, then one of the two values will be undefined, and no mean can be obtained. This can be fixed by just using the value of the available neighbour, as specified below
2. If two values in a row are very low, the leftmost one will use the rightmost one to calculate its value, which will result in a very low value. This is a problem that may not occur for you in practice, but it is an inherent result of the way you wish to recalculate values, and you might want to keep it in mind.

Improved version, keeping in mind the edge cases:

```py
# don't alter the first and last item, even if they're low
arr = [arr[i] if arr[i] >= 50 or i == 0 or i+1 == len(arr) else (arr[i-1]+arr[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(arr))]

# replace the first and last element if needed
if arr[0] < 50:
  arr[0] = arr[1]
if arr[len(arr)-1] < 50:
  arr[len(arr)-1] = arr[len(arr)-2]
```

I hope this answer was useful for you, even if you intend to use another language or framework than python.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using python actually. Your answer helped me. I appreciate it

Comment: No problem :) If you feel like your question is answered you can mark the answer as the 'accepted answer'